# How to take country_iso_code from selected country name from the spinner android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-spinner

I have a spinner and I am selecting country name from it and saving it as a String to pass it via JSON object.

I also want to pass country ISO code the same way so how can i get country iso code from my selected country name?

I tried this but gives me run time exception that it can't cast `String` into `Locale`.

```
String countryName = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (mSpinner.getSelectedItemId() == 0) 
    Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, "select ur country", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (mSpinner.getSelectedItemId() != 0)
    Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, countryName +" is your selected country",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Locale cName = (Locale) mSpinner.getSelectedItem(); //exception occurs here...
String countryCode = cName.getCountry();
```

As I can't get country code from string countryName I again took the selected item as locale object but I get an exception saying:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.util.Locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the country name as the country code to get the locale. So getting the error:

```
Locale cName = (Locale) mSpinner.getSelectedItem(); //exception occurs here...
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Locale

Locale takes the countrycode as a parameter:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("", countryCode);
```

You could try something like this:

```
String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

Locale locale;

for (String countryCode : locales) {

    locale = new Locale("", countryCode);

    if(locale.getDisplayCountry().equals(cName){
        countryCode = locale.getCountry();
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ms Yvette....I made changes as you said code is mentioned above...I am facing a minor issue can you find where I am missing something...I hope description is clear..!

Comment: thank you for guidance....I will keep this in mind next time.. coming back to my issue I am experiencing an issue were after selecting a country and executing break; statement my countryCode values is not getting sustained... I observed this in debugging mode..How to make it sustain its value? As I have to pass this as JSON object next alongside country name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930290/not-able-to-sustain-value-of-a-string-variable-after-leaving-the-class thank you for your guidance this is the new question with brief description of sustaining value issue...hope this will make sense.... waiting for reply...thank you in advance