# Not able to Sustain value of a string variable after leaving the class

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I want to sustain countryCode from selected countryName from a spinner dropdown list. This is my code after completing this code I want to sustain countryName and mCountryCode value and take it to new activity to use it in JSON object. I have got country code from locale object and put it in an arraylist country name to populate the spinner. After user selects country name I want that selected country name to be country code again and store it in a string value. All works fine till break line. Selected countryName is there in string countryCode is also there but after I leave the class mCountryCode value is not there.

I think variable scope is something I need to work on...

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    String mCountryCode;
        onCreate{
        final String[] isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
        //filling spinner object with countryName array using isoCountryCodes array
        countryName.add("Select A country");
        for (String countryCode : isoCountryCodes) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("", countryCode);
            countryName.add(locale.getDisplayCountry());
        }
       //spinner object has been set with array adapter and that works fine below is how to 
       //handle selected countryName and convert it to countryCode again and sustain its value 
       //in a string variable so along with countryName, the corresponding countryCode can be sent via JSON object...

        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            mCountryName = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Locale locale;
            for (String candidate : isoCountryCodes) {
                locale = new Locale("", candidate);
                if (locale.getDisplayCountry().equals(mSpinner.getSelectedItem())) {
                    mCountryCode = candidate;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: under the intent you're using to call the new activity use intent.putExtra("keyCountry",mCountryCode)

Comment: tried..it doesnt work...gives null values in mCountryCode variable even after selecting country...it leaves value null after break; line

Answer (score -1):

**Request**
If someone thinks this should have been a comment rather than answer, please don't downvote as I can't add comments being a beginner having low reputation points.

**Answer:**
The problem is that you are using same name (mCountryCode) for two different variables, once as a global variable and then as a local variable for for loop. The value you are assigning in the line just before "break", is actually getting assigned to local variable instead of the global one.

Solution is to just change the name of local variable in teh for loop. Below code segment for "for loop" should work:

```
Locale locale;
for (String countryCode : isoCountryCodes) {
locale = new Locale("", countryCode);                                
    if(locale.getDisplayCountry().equals(mSpinner.getSelectedItem())){
        mCountryCode = locale.getCountry();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have replaced the new code with creating new var in for loop and assigning that to mcountrycode.. still same result...